# Disable future date selection in date range picker in default google's material date range picker in android?

Tags: android, datepicker, material-design, android-datepicker, daterangepicker

I want to select past date to max current date. There is methods like setMinDate() and setMaxDate() in single date selection in date picker. But, how i can do that in **date range selection** in **material date range picker**?

Answer (score 4):

You have to use **CalendarConstraints** for Minimum and Maximum dates restriction in Date Range picker.

```
val constraintsBuilderRange = CalendarConstraints.Builder()
val dateValidatorMin: DateValidator = DateValidatorPointForward.from(millisOfMinimum)
val dateValidatorMax: DateValidator = DateValidatorPointBackward.before(millisOfMaximum)

 val listValidators = ArrayList<DateValidator>()
 listValidators.add(dateValidatorMin)
 listValidators.add(dateValidatorMax)
 val validators = CompositeDateValidator.allOf(listValidators)
 constraintsBuilderRange.setValidator(validators)


 val datePicker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
                .setTitleText("Select range")
                .setCalendarConstraints(constraintsBuilderRange.build())
                .build()
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your current date in **setMaxDate()**

And **setMinDate()**  whatever you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        showRangePickerDialog()

    }

    private fun showRangePickerDialog() {
        val builderRange = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()

        builderRange.setCalendarConstraints(defineRange().build())
        val pickerRange = builderRange.build()
        pickerRange.show(supportFragmentManager, pickerRange.toString())
    }


    private fun defineRange(): CalendarConstraints.Builder {

        val constraintsBuilderRange = CalendarConstraints.Builder()

        val calendarStart: Calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance()
        val calendarEnd: Calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance()

        val year = 2020

        calendarStart.set(year, 1, 1)
        calendarEnd.set(year, 6, 30)

        val minDate = calendarStart.timeInMillis
        val maxDate = calendarEnd.timeInMillis

        constraintsBuilderRange.setStart(minDate)
        constraintsBuilderRange.setEnd(maxDate)

        constraintsBuilderRange.setValidator(RangeValidator(minDate, maxDate))

        return constraintsBuilderRange
            }

    }

    class RangeValidator(private val minDate:Long, private val maxDate:Long) : CalendarConstraints.DateValidator{


    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readLong(),
        parcel.readLong()
    )

    override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel?, flags: Int) {
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
    }

    override fun isValid(date: Long): Boolean {
        return !(minDate > date || maxDate < date)

    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<RangeValidator> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): RangeValidator {
            return RangeValidator(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<RangeValidator?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

Try the above code but have to do some changes in range as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Just add these two lines of code in your code and you can prevent future date selection.

**maxDate: moment().subtract(0, 'days'),**
**"This Month": [moment().startOf("month"), moment().subtract(0, 'days')],**

```js
    var rangesVal = {
      position: "inherit",
      drops: "down",
      maxDate: moment().subtract(0, 'days'),
      minDate: minDate,
      opens: "center",
      maxSpan: {
        months: 12,
      },
      ranges: {
        Today: [moment(), moment()],
        Yesterday: [moment().subtract(1, "days"), moment().subtract(1, "days")],
        "Last 7 Days": [moment().subtract(6, "days"), moment()],
        "Last 30 Days": [moment().subtract(29, "days"), moment()],
        "This Month": [moment().startOf("month"), moment().subtract(0, 'days')],
        "Last Month": [
          moment().subtract(1, "month").startOf("month"),
          moment().subtract(1, "month").endOf("month"),
        ],
      },
    };
```